# Making a Marginal Distribution from Joint Distribution in python

Tags: python, arrays, distribution

I have 3 arrays of X values, Y values, and probabilities. I'm trying to do two things but they're practically the same coding wise I imagine.

I want to find all the X values that are the same, and add up the corresponding probabilities into another array. (So if my X values are [3,7,4,7] and my probabilities are [.2,.3,.1,.4] I would want to add .3 and .4 together. I'm trying to do this with a loop, but because I only picked up python two weeks ago I'm struggling.

My thought process that I want to try:

```python
MargX=np.unique(X array)
MargXp=np.zeros(len(MargX))

for Ind in range(len(MargX):
    ?
```

(Here I want to take the values in my X array that are equal, grab the corresponding value from my p array, and then add them into my zero array MargXp)

I've tried a couple of different ways to set up my loop so that it would add the values into the zero arrays that I made, but to no avail because I keep getting syntax errors and various other things.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to compact the X's down with `unique`, then finding the corresponding probabilities would involve searching through the X array for indices and using those to find the corresponding probabilities.  I think you'd be happier using python's dictionary concept to associate keys (x-values) with values (probabilities).  Using `defaultdict` allows you to specify a default value for keys which aren't already in the dictionary.  In this case, start off with the idea that an arbitrary x-value has zero probability.  As you iterate through the x/probability pairs, you can then use increment to add the probability to the stored or default value associated with the x.

The result looks something like this:

```python
from collections import defaultdict

# synchronized arrays from your example.
x = [3, 7, 4, 7]
probs = [0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4]

marginal = defaultdict(lambda: 0.0) # 0.0 is the default value
for key, value in zip(x, probs):    # zip combines the arrays as pairs
    marginal[key] += value          # increment to accumulate total probability

# The following line is not strictly needed since all values are
# in the dictionary, but by default key values are not ordered.
orderedkeys = sorted(marginal.keys())

for key in orderedkeys:
    print(key, marginal[key])
```

which produces:

```text
3 0.2
4 0.1
7 0.7
```